# Can I set seriescollection.values in such a way that it is the difference between an array and a range?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a simple forecasting tool in Excel which contains several dynamically created groups of charts via VBA.

Each group contains two charts.  The first chart plots a static set of data stored in an array as well as user input in a range.  I would like the second to plot the difference between the user input (range) data and the static data (array).

I'm not having any problems setting the data for the first chart:

```
objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).values = testForecast.Forecast(i)
objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = groupActualRange
```

but I'm not having any luck when it comes to the second.

Is there any way to set the values for the second chart without having to create a second array to store to differences between the values and set application.volatile to true to capture new input?

Comment: You might be better off returning your forecast values to a range and plotting them (and the difference) from the sheet instead of assigning arrays to the series values. Then once it's set up you won't have to re-assign values any time the inputs change.